# Continuations and implicit conversions

Tags: scala, continuations, implicit-conversion

I was experimenting with continuations, and I came across a case that seems to suggest that @cpsParam thwarts implicit conversions.

I have

```
def v: T @cpsParam[Unit, Unit]
// ...and then later
v must_== 42
// where must_== is from specs/mockito
```

I get the compiler error:

```
must_== is not a member of Int @cpsParam[Unit,Unit]
```

A more complete code sample is available on [gist](https://gist.github.com/798562).

Is there a simple mistake I've made?

Thanks,
Topher.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where must_== method is defined. But you should probably import the implicit conversion method and not only the class/trait/object. It means, you should write something like this:

`import foo.bar.Bar.convert // OK`

or this:

`import foo.bar.Bar._ // OK`

and not this

`import foo.bar.Bar // Bad: The implicit conversion method is not imported!`

Comment: The example code on gist brings the necessary implicit defs into scope through the traits/classes it extends.